# Check for negative values when using lexical_cast to unsigned type

Tags: c++, boost

I have a situation where I am grabbing command line arguments and using `boost::lexical_cast<unsigned long>(my_param)`. I was hoping that negative values of my_param would cause lexical_cast to throw, but instead it happily converts them, with -1 becoming `18446744073709551615`. Which seems absurd, as the max value for an unsigned long is 2^32-1, it looks much more like an unsigned long long.

So I am looking for either a smarter way to cast the char * input to unsigned long, or a way to verify that I have not accepted a negative value in its disguise as a large unsigned long long.

Comment: `if (my_param && *my_param != '-')` ?

Comment: @ForEveR: And if there are leading spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug report against boost with your problem which explains why it behaves that way:

> boost::lexical_cast has the behavior of stringstream, which uses num_get functions of std::locale to convert numbers. If we look at the [22.2.2.1.2] of Programming languages — C++ ( or at [22.2.2.1.2] Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++) we`ll see, that num_get uses the rules of scanf for conversions. And in the C99 standard for %u the input value minus sign is optional, so if a negative number is read, no errors will arise and the result will be the two's complement.

And also a suggested wrapper workaround:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5494

Comment: The approach of checking for the '-' is where I figured this would go. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Note that ticket #5494 is marked as "closed Bugs: wontfix". They don't think this is a bug. It's behaving exactly as expected.

Comment: @DavidHammen: If it weren't a bug, it would be marked "INVALID", not "WONTFIX".

Comment: @BenVoigt: Please. You've never marked a bug that you know full well is invalid as wontfix to mollify the person who reported the bug? People take extreme umbrage when they are told that their report is invalid. They only take umbrage when they are told that the bug won't be fixed. The wording of comment #2 says that the bug is "invalid" rather than "wontfix".

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how negative values are to be treated per the standard. They use modulo 2<sup>N</sup> arithmetic. This enables a handy trick: Using -1 as shorthand for the largest possible unsigned value of some type.

If you don't like this conversion, you'll have to scan the input for a minus sign before doing the conversion.

Comment: `lexical_cast` is not arithmetic, however

Comment: So? `sscanf()` with a `%u` scan directive, `strtoul()`, and `operator>>(unsigned &)` when applied to a string value of `-1` works just like `some_unsigned_int=-1;`. It's the principle of least astonishment. It's doing just what it should do. Anything else would be a bit astonishing.

Comment: If formatting and parsing code returns a value which is congruent to but not equal to the input, that's astonishing.  Formatting and parsing should return the value which is input, if representable, or an error if not.

Comment: -1 **is** equal to 18446744073709551615 as far as `unsigned long` is concerned (on a 64 bit Linux machine). YMMV with respect to `sizeof(unsigned long)` and hence the value of -1.

Comment: No, it's not equal.  `(unsigned long)(-1)` is equal to that, but `-1` and `18446744073709551615` are only congruent, not equal.